# How to know which ENI is attached to a pod in an AWS EKS Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, networking, containers, amazon-eks

"Amazon EKS supports native VPC networking via the [Amazon VPC Container Network Interface (CNI)](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s) plugin for Kubernetes. The CNI plugin allows Kubernetes Pods to have the same IP address inside the Pod as they do on the VPC network. The CNI plugin uses [Elastic Network Interface (ENI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html) for Pod networking. The CNI allocates ENIs to each worker node and uses the secondary IP range from each ENI for pods. The CNI pre-allocates ENIs and IP addresses for faster pod startup."

I want to know the ENI id attached to my pod and using AWS CNI plugin for networking. I had a couple of questions in mind:

1. Is there a command to know which ENI is attached to a pod? From ip address of the node, I can get the network interface attached to it but couldn't find a way for the pod?
2. https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/115_sg-per-pod/30_cni_config/ - I was reading this page. There is an env called "ENABLE_POD_ENI". Does this need to be true for the pods to have an ENI? If it is false, what's the difference?

```
      ENABLE_IPv4:                             true
      ENABLE_IPv6:                            false
      ENABLE_POD_ENI:                         false
```

3. Currently I have a cluster up with running pods. They seems to have the IP addresses. Is it because of the ENABLE_IPv4=true. Can those IP addresses help me in finding the ENI id?

From IP address of the node, I can get the network interface attached to it but I want to find the same for the pod which I am unable to find.

I know VPC Flows could help me here to identify the pods and the requests made by them. But I want to know if there is a command which could help me identify the ENI of a pod without it?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to view that just from the ENI, because Pod IPs can be recycled; [those ENIs are tagged](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s@v1.12.0/-/blob/pkg/awsutils/awsutils.go?L54:29) but not per-Pod

Answer (score 0):

In AWS Console,
You can go to the Network Interface page (https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=#NIC) and enter the Pod IP in the search box. That will show you the ENI of the IP.